# how to fetch jsf <h:selectOneRadio> value in javascript on click of submit button before submitting the page

Tags: jsf

how to fetch jsf  value in javascript on click of submit button before submitting the page

javascript code

function validate(form)
{
   alert(form['f1:radio1'].value);
}

Answer (score 1):

Set the value of the radio when selected to a hidden value, like

```
<h:inputHidden id="radioValue" />
<h:selectOneRadio id="radio" onclick="document.getElementById('radioValue').value = this.value;">
```

And then you can get the value of `inputHidden` on submit button click